# Printing an array list sorted and breaking lines with Dart

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, dart

Given the array = [8, -14, 15]

How would I be able to print it sorted and breaking a line after each value, no commas or brackets, just the line breaks?

Like

```
-14
8
15
```

I tried all above and variations.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
List<String> list = stdin.readLineSync().split(' ');
    int a = int.parse(list[0]);
    int b = int.parse(list[1]);
    int c = int.parse(list[2]);

list.sort();

print(list.sort()[0]);
print(list[1]);
print(list[2]);
print('\n$a\n$b\n$c');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you use `.sort()` on a list of Strings so the list is not numerically sorted but alphabetically sorted. You need to convert the list of String to a list of ints:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = '8 -14 15'.split(' ');
  List<int> ints = list.map(int.parse).toList();
  ints.sort();
  ints.forEach(print);
}
```